# 'Deriving' the Laplace Transform from the $z$ Transform: Missing a $\Delta t$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

Textbooks normally give the following 'derivation' (or justification, if you prefer) of the z-Transform from the Laplace Transform. Let $x(t)$ be a signal defined on $t\geq 0$, and write a discretized version of $x(t)$ as:
$$
x_d(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x(n\Delta t)\delta(t-n\Delta t)
$$
where $\delta()$ is the Dirac delta function. Take the Laplace Transform of $x_d(t)$:
$$
\mathcal{L}\{x_d(t)\}= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x(n\Delta t)\mathcal{L}\{\delta(t-nT)\}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x(n\Delta t) e^{-sn\Delta t} =^{z=e^{s\Delta t}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x(n\Delta t) z^{-n} = X(z)
$$
I wish demonstrate to someone who is already familiar with the $z$ Transform that the Laplace Transform is its continuous analogue, so I wish to do the above process in reverse. I am trying the following approach:

Consider a discrete-time signal $x[n]$ as a sampled version of a continuous signal: $x[n]=x(n\Delta t)$ and let $z=e^{s\Delta t}$:
$$
X(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x(n\Delta t) e^{-sn\Delta t}
$$

What I'm going for is to argue that as $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, this sum becomes an integral and therefore the Laplace Transform. But there is a 'missing' $\Delta t$ inside the sum for it to match the definition of a Riemann integral.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what I am missing.

---

Notes:

- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvbdoSeGAgI) from MIT ignores the problem altogether and just writes an integral $dt$.
- [This attempt](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/Laplace/Laplace_4up.pdf) from Stanford does something weird which seems wrong to me.

Comment: I think you need to do some kind of renormalization here. For instance, assume that the discrete signal is measuring the "energy" of the signal, so as you make the time intervals shorter, the discrete signals must go to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole problem lies in the fact that the discretized version of the $x$ is not what is claimed unless $\Delta t=1$. In fact, the right discrete version should be
$$
x_d(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n\Delta t)\color{red}{\Delta t}\,\delta(t-n\Delta t)
$$
which converges in the sense of distributions to $x(t)$, and not the proposed one.
Indeed, if $\varphi$ is a test function then
$$
\langle x_d,\varphi\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n\Delta t)\,\varphi(n\Delta t)\,\Delta t \mathop{\longrightarrow}_{\Delta t\to0}\int_0^\infty x(t)\varphi(t)dt
$$
while clearly this does not hold when we consider the version of discretized signal proposed in the OP's question.

Now, with the new formula of the $x_d$ every thing works.